# Notifications API, showing multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

I'm using the chrome(Mozilla, etc) notifications API:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                    // Whatever the user answers, we make sure we store the information
                    if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
                        Notification.permission = permission;
                    }

                    // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
                    if (permission === "granted") {
                        var options = {
                            body: data.nome + ': ' + data.corpo,
                            icon: data.img,
                            dir : "ltr"
                        };
                        var notification = new Notification("Weeazy",options);
                    }
            });
```

When i'm with 2 or more windows opened, the notification shows multiple times (1 per window).
Someone knows how i can prevent this? I just want to show 1 notification, even with 2, or 999 windows opened, like Facebook does. I hope my code example can help! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I know it was a long time ago, but did you manage to do this?

Comment: @ÁlvaroMenezes I haven't worked on this, but we can try to solve together... 

Do you have any source code with the problem?

Comment: I've just made an example using firebase sdk for registration and everything seems to be working fine.
https://github.com/beebee-logistica/testes-web-notification